# Запрос данных из фейк API с помощью fetchAll

Tags: reactjs, api

У меня есть фейк API c выводом данных через fetchAll

```
const users = [
    {
        _id: 'id1fd3b2a30163',
        name: 'Эндре Хифон'
    },
    {
        _id: 'id6130f39a3d55b',
        name: 'Факир Валунтас'
    },
    {
        _id: 'ide72070fe6000d',
        name: 'Клаус Кэнтерберийский'
    }
    ]

const fetchAll = () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            resolve(users)
        }, 2000)
    })

export default {
    fetchAll
}
```

Далее данные приходят в компонент

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import api from '../api'

const Authors = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
        api.users.fetchAll().then((data) => setUsers(data))
    }, [])
return (
<div>
{users.map((user) => (
  <div key={user._id}>
    <h1>{user.name}</h1>
  </div>
)}
</div>
}
```

Но мне приходит ошибка

```
_api__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.users.fetchAll is not a function
TypeError: _api__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.users.fetchAll is not a function
```

Я не могу понять в чем проблема. Может кто подсказать? Извините, если пример не идеально написан. Поправьте меня если считаете нужным.

Comment: вам нужно поместить функцию `fetchAll` в объект `users`

Comment: после `const fetchAll` и следующей функции поместите это `users.fetchAll = fetchAll`

Answer (score 1):

Судя по ошибке, у вас нет метода `fetchAll` у объекта `users`.

В своём файле замените тот кусок кода, который у вас в вопросе, таким:

```js
const users = [
    {
        _id: 'id1fd3b2a30163',
        name: 'Эндре Хифон'
    },
    {
        _id: 'id6130f39a3d55b',
        name: 'Факир Валунтас'
    },
    {
        _id: 'ide72070fe6000d',
        name: 'Клаус Кэнтерберийский'
    }
    ]

const fetchAll = () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            resolve(users)
        }, 2000)
    })

// тут добавляем функцию fetchAll как метод объекту users
users.fetchAll = fetchAll;

export default {
    fetchAll
}
```

В вышеприведённом примере используется вариант присвоения свойства объекту. Свойство и его название может быть любым.

Comment: Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте

Comment: Мне этот вариант не помог.
Помог только такая конструкция
```const users = [
    {
        _id: 'id1fd3b2a30163',
        name: 'Эндре Хифон'
    },
    {
        _id: 'id6130f39a3d55b',
        name: 'Факир Валунтас'
    },
    {
        _id: 'ide72070fe6000d',
        name: 'Клаус Кэнтерберийский'
    }
    ]
export function fetchAll() {
    return users
}```
А в компоненте
const [users] = useState(api.users.fetchAll())

Но это временное решение и так оставлять нельзя.

Comment: @user20389696 как знаете, может у вас код в вопросе не тот...

Comment: Не успел дописать, случайно отправил. Проблема так и не решилась.
Использование 
```
export function fetchAll() {
    return users
}
```
и
const [users] = useState(api.users.fetchAll())
не решает проблемы

Comment: Попробуйте оставить такой же код, как у вас в вопросе, но в компоненте использовать не `api.users.fetchAll`, а просто `api.fetchAll`

Comment: Увы это не помогло.
console log выдает пустой массив. Но это крайне странно получается данные в компонент не поступают в принципе. Но по какой причине... в голову ничего не приходит.

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено. Проблема в экспорте.
Надо было написать так

```
export const fetchAll = () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            resolve(users)
        }, 2000)
    })
```